# I am trying to run a battleship game pygame font I get Expected type 'str | bytes | Iterable[str | bytes]', got 'None'

Tags: python, pycharm

Code:

```
import pygame

hidden_patterns = [[' '] * 10 for _ in range(10)]
guess_patterns = [[' '] * 10 for _ in range(10)]
letter_num = {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 3, 'E': 4, 'F': 5, 'G': 6, 'H': 7, 'I': 8, 'J': 9}


def draw_board(board, screen):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)#the problem is here in this line and idk why i get it#
    for row in range(10):
        for col in range(10):
            text = font.render(board[row][col], True, (255, 255, 255))
            if text is not None:
                x = col * 40 + 40
                y = row * 40 + 100
                screen.blit(text, (x, y))



def get_ship_location(player):
    print("Player", player, "turn:")
    row = input('Please enter a ship row (1-10): ')
    while row not in '12345678910':
        print("Please enter a valid row")
        row = input('Please enter a ship row (1-10): ')
    column = input('Please enter a ship column (A-J): ').upper()
    while column not in 'ABCDEFGHIJ':
        print("Please enter a valid column")
        column = input('Please enter a ship column (A-J): ')
    return int(row) - 1, letter_num[column]
```

I tried asking chatgpt to help me but it repeats the same answers for the problem. The problem is in the draw_board function and when I run this program it opens the pygame window and then it becomes unresponsive. There is more to the code but I can't upload.

Comment: You are explicitly passing `None` as the first argument to `SysFont`. What do you think that does?

Comment: Is this a runtime error, or a static type-checking error?